# Error showing in my practice? "Unexpected character after attribute value"

Tags: javascript, html

New to using HTML and Javascript and trying to practice just placing text, buttons, etc. Getting "Unexpected Character After attribute value".
What does this mean? i still am able to place everything so should i just ignore it? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Computer Programming</h1>
    <p style="text-align:center;">Programming Language List</p>
    <ul>
        <li> <button style='color:red';>HTML</button> </li>
        <li> <button style='color:blue';>JAVASCRIPT</button></li>
        <li> <button style='color:green';>CSS</button> </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've got your CSS semicolons outside the quotes for the attribute values (sometimes).

Comment: @Pointy I can't believe i missed that. Sorry if it was a dumb question but i appreciate the help!

Comment: Note that you don't really need the last semicolon in the "style" attribute string.

Answer (score 3):

Check your semicolons on your button tag, they have to be inside quotes like:

```
<button style='color:green;'>CSS</button>
```